# Spring Integration (DSL): Run two JPA queries in the same transaction

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

How can I make two JPA queries run in the same transaction?

See example below. If the second query is failing I want the first one to be rollbacked.

```
    @Bean
    IntegrationFlow dbFlow() {
      return IntegrationFlows.from("poiChannel")
        .routeToRecipients(r -> r
          .recipientFlow(
            (f) -> f.handle(Jpa.outboundAdapter(entityManagerFactory)
                .jpaQuery("delete from PointOfInterest"),
              e -> e.transactional()
            )
          )
          .recipientFlow(
            (f) -> f.handle(Jpa.outboundAdapter(entityManagerFactory)
                .entityClass(PointOfInterest.class),
               e -> e.transactional(true)
            )
          )
        )
        .get();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, seems that I just have to move the `transactional()` command one level up to the `routeToRecipients()` flow.

```
    @Bean
    IntegrationFlow dbFlow() {
      return IntegrationFlows.from("poiChannel")
        .routeToRecipients(r -> r
          .recipientFlow(
            (f) -> f.handle(Jpa.outboundAdapter(entityManagerFactory)
                .jpaQuery("delete from PointOfInterest")
            )
          )
          .recipientFlow(
            (f) -> f.handle(Jpa.outboundAdapter(entityManagerFactory)
                .entityClass(PointOfInterest.class)
            )
          )
          .transactional()
        )
        .get();
    }
```

Comment: Well, that's definitely correct logic. Your two JPA recipients work in their separate sub-flow. It is really expected that they don't effect each other. To make both sub-flows working in the same transaction you indeed have to move a transaction definition on top of both sub-flows.

Comment: Thank you @ArtemBilan. Also generally for being so active here and answering all the Spring Integration questions.